# Allow EFCore [Required]-Attribute to be nullable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Since EFCore, the `IsOptional`-Method was removed from the FluentAPI. I've found this question here [Required property but Nullable, Entity Framework through Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38799903/required-property-but-nullable-entity-framework-through-code-first), where using `IsOptional` was a solution for this issue.

What to do now? I'd like to use my EFCore models for both validation and storage but the rules do differ (e.g. Email is allowed to be null in the Database, but not for the validation).

Comment: The first and accepted answer of the link you posted suggests you to create a new model.  I would suggest creating a ViewModel folder were to put you app's related models (like creating, editing) and all the "original" DB models would be placed on a DataAccessLibrary. Then just map them.

Comment: I'm working with a pretty complicated Framework that forces using the EFCore models for WebAPI, too. Serialization / Deserialization is controlled by interfaces so they can be used directly. Is there no chance with the latest EFCore version?

Comment: Posted it as an enhavement in Github, maybe there is no solution for this, yet: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25935

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: `IsRequired(false)` - there is an overload that replaces `IsOptional()`.

Thank to @roji @Github